# Delete Row based on Cell value in Multiple Sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, delete-row

I have a code to click button to delete row. But it only work for the sheet where the button being placed. (It well delete cell that contain text "Delete"). How to amend the code so that if the button located in Sheet 1, the delete row button can delete same row in Sheet 1, Sheet 2 and Sheet 3 as well?

This is my current code.

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners10_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("a9:zz2000")
    Do
        Set A = rng.Find("Delete*", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not A Is Nothing Then A.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not A Is Nothing
    End Sub

Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Added lines are marked with `added`

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners10_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("a9:zz2000")
    Do
        Set a = rng.find("Delete*", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not a Is Nothing Then
            todel = a.Row                             'added
            a.EntireRow.Delete
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(todel).Delete   'added
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows(todel).Delete   'added
        End If
    Loop While Not a Is Nothing
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Rows in Multiple Sheets Based on Cell Value in the First

```vb
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners10_Click()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const DST_SHEETS As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A9"
    Const CRITERIA_STRING As String = "Delete*" ' begins with
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Return the worksheet names in an array.
    
    Dim wsNames() As String: wsNames = Split(DST_SHEETS, ",")
    Dim UB As Long: UB = UBound(wsNames)
    
    ' Reference the first worksheet and range.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(wsNames(0)) ' the first
    
    Dim rg As Range: ' the first
    
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set rg = ws.Range(ws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL), .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge))
    End With
        
    ' All but the first range to an array.
    
    Dim nRanges() As Range: ReDim nRanges(0 To UB)
        
    Dim n As Long
        
    For n = 1 To UB ' the first (0) is 'rg'
        Set nRanges(n) = wb.Sheets(wsNames(n)).Range(rg.Address)
    Next n
        
    ' Define the union ranges array.
        
    Dim uRanges() As Range: ReDim uRanges(0 To UB)
    
    ' Combine the matching rows into the ranges in the union ranges array.
    
    Dim rrg As Range, r As Long
    
    For Each rrg In rg.Rows
        r = r + 1
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(CRITERIA_STRING, rrg, 0)) Then
            If uRanges(0) Is Nothing Then
                Set uRanges(0) = rrg
                For n = 1 To UB
                    Set uRanges(n) = nRanges(n).Rows(r)
                Next n
            Else
                Set uRanges(0) = Union(uRanges(0), rrg)
                For n = 1 To UB
                    Set uRanges(n) = Union(uRanges(n), nRanges(n).Rows(r))
                Next n
            End If
        End If
    Next rrg
    
    ' Delete the ranges and inform.
    
    If uRanges(0) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No rows deleted.", vbExclamation
    Else
        For n = 0 To UB
            uRanges(n).Delete xlShiftUp
        Next n
        MsgBox "Rows deleted.", vbInformation
    End If
            
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Please, try the next way. It will create a helper column and based on it, a filter will be applied and its (visible) rows, except the header, will be deleted. So, it should be fast enough even for huge ranges:

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners10_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, delRng As Range, rngMark As Range, rngFilt As Range
    Dim strAddress As String, arrMark, latR As Long

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A9:AA2000")
    ReDim arrMark(1 To rng.rows.count, 1 To 1) 'reDim the helper array keeping the markers
    
    arrMark(1, 1) = "Marker" 'Place the header in the array first row
    ' Search target cells in Sheet1
    Set delRng = rng.Find("Delete*", lookat:=xlWhole, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then
        strAddress = delRng.address
        Do
            arrMark(delRng.row - rng.row + 1, 1) = "Del" 'place the marker in the right position
            Set delRng = rng.FindNext(delRng)
        Loop While delRng.address <> strAddress
    End If
    If strAddress <> "" Then
        ' Delete those rows in the next three sheets:
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
            If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False 'remove the filter if it exists
            Set rngMark = ws.Range("AAA9") 'set the markers/helper column starting cell
            rngMark.Resize(UBound(arrMark), 1).Value2 = arrMark 'drop the array content at once
            ws.Range("A9:AAA" & UBound(arrMark)).AutoFilter rng.Columns.count + 1, "Del" 'auto filter by this column
            
            rng.Resize(rng.rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        Next ws
    End If
End Sub
```